# How to move an axios call into its own method using vuex and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, async-await, axios, vuex

I have a method in vuex actions that calls the api and updates the user information.  What I am trying to do is move the axios call into its own method and have not had any luck.

Here is my code

```
async updateProfile({ commit, dispatch }: any, user: User):Promise<User> {
    console.log(user)
    console.log("currentUser")

    const response = await axios.request({
        method: "PUT",
        url: `/users/me/profile`,
        data: user
    });
    //  dispatch('updateUserProfile', user);
   
    console.log(response)
    console.log("response")
    return user;
    // return response;
},
async updateUserProfile(user: any): Promise<User> {
    return await axios.request({
        method: "PUT",
        url: `/users/me/profile`,
        data: user
      });
},
```

The line commented out dispatch is trying to call the axios method and pass the user as a parameter.  When I try that line instead of the axios.request I get a 400 error.  When I change user: any to user: User I get an  Types of property 'actions' are incompatible. error

Comment: Have you checked your API to see what is wrong? A 400 Bad Request usually comes from validation errors (e.g. min/max length, not empty, etc) and similar malformed requests.

Comment: Why are either of these Vuex actions at all? They don't commit any mutations or even read state 

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs are different. One has a leading slash, the other one hasn't. And your second action should have `{}` as first param. Should be `async updateUserProfile({}, user: any)`. This probably explains why you're getting a 400. Your request payload is probably empty, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining both `updateProfile` and `updateUserProfile` as vuex actions? If so, the latter doesn't look like an action at all; the first arg for all actions is the *context*.

Just make it a stand-alone function, separate from your store entirely

```js
// could even be in another file / module entirely
const updateUserProfile = (user: User) =>
  axios.put<User>("/users/me/profile", user)
```

From an action, you would just call this directly

```js
// S = state type, R = root state type
async yourAction({ commit }: ActionContext<S, R>, user: User): Promise<User> {
  const response = await updateUserProfile(user)

  // here's where you would commit something

  return user // or whatever
}
```

Comment: While I think you're totally right when you say that the API call should not be a store action, I think you're also missing to tell what the simple mistake is, i.e. wrong signature for the action.

Comment: @v-moe I specifically mentioned _"the first arg for all actions is the context"_

Comment: Fair enough. "context" should be a well-known concept for JS developers after all. Please forget my comment